# No translucent views after project migration from iOS 6 to iOS 7

Tags: migration, ios7, uitoolbar

a few weeks ago i migrated my current project (developed on xcode 4.6) to iOS 7 (xcode 5 DP6).
Now i noticed that the translucent effect of the UIToolBar/UINavigationbar is not working in my project (It is only transparent).
But if i create a complete new project it works as expected.
Further i noticed that xcode dosen't find the complete iOS 7 SDK (Also only in my project).
Maybe i missed some configuration.
(I only changed the deployment traget to iOS 7)

some ideas?

Thanks in advance

Regards

Comment: I'm not sure if this is your problem, but let me try: Have you changed only the deployment target? Confirm if your Base SDK in build setting is set to iOS 7.0, that is the one that matters.

Comment: Yes the build settings sdk is set to iOS 7. I looked through all project settings i know. Everything should be set to iOS 7.

Comment: But the bar looks like new one, except without the blur? What device you are testing? Some older iOS devices don't have the translucent effect, instead of that it uses a slightly transparent white.

Comment: Yes the bar looks like the new one. Tested on iPhone 5